# In NextJS Is it possible to have custom _app.js read a slug, getInitialProps and pass those props to every component including all pages?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js, next-router

I have looked around the docs to see if I can have _app.js read a slug (nothing mentioned about it). I need this slug to be added to an HTTP get request to grab the proper data that then then returns results to _app.js in which I can then use to pass props to all components and pages.

Example: when I go to http://localhost:3000/some-business-name , _app.js can grab the slug (some-business-name), do the request, and pass props to all components and pages in the project.

But what I am really struggling to do is get the App props to pass to all the rest of the pages inside the pages folder.

In my pages folder I have:

1. _app.js -- (what I need to pass props to all pages)
2. [slug].js -- (root page that used to detect slug and now I need for it to just receive props from _app.js)
3. success.js -- (need to receive props from _app.js)
4. error.js -- (need to receive props from _app.js)

I am using a data file that is an array of business data objects to which I use to test dynamic routing with.

I have looked in the NextJS docs and I am having an issue understanding how this can be done. I still need for the slug to exist, I just need help understanding how I can get _app.js to completely take over dynamic routing.

My code for _app.js is:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import { businesses } from '../data';

export default function MyApp({ Component, appProps }) {
  return (
    <Component appProps={appProps} />
  )
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ appContext }) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(slug);
  return {appProps};
};

App.getInitialProps = async (slug) => {
  const business = businesses.filter((business) => {
    return business.slug === slug;
  });
  return business[0];
};
```

Currently my [slug].js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import LandingPage from '../components/landing-page';

export default function Slug(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm' crossOrigin='anonymous' />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap' rel='stylesheet' />
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN' crossOrigin='anonymous'></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q' crossOrigin='anonymous'></script>
        <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl' crossOrigin='anonymous'></script>
      </Head>

      <LandingPage businessInfo={props.appProps}/>

      <style global jsx>{`
          body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
          }
        `}</style>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Surprisingly I am able to receive App props on the LandingPage component in [slug].js but not in the success.js and error.js pages.

Any help is extremely appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did this work for you? Which approach did you take?

Comment: I haven't been able to get a "fetch" to work within getInitialProps.. on page refresh... nothing ever fires..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import { Router } from '../routes'

class MyApp extends App {
  // Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
  // every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
  // perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
  // be server-side rendered.
  //
  // static async getInitialProps(appContext) {
  //   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  //   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  //
  //   return { ...appProps }
  // }

  render() {
    const { Component, appProps } = this.props
    // Workaround for https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8592
    const { err } = this.props
    const modifiedPageProps = { ...appProps, err }
    return (
        <div id="comp-wrapp">
          <Component {...modifiedPageProps} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: so this goes in my custom _app.js?

Comment: yes but if you are really not have any static pages. Only uncomment the getInitialMethod if you have blocking data requirements for every single page in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Better would do it this was

```
class NextDocument extends Document {
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    const { req } = ctx
    // pass down everything u need there
    return { ...initialProps, locale }
}
```